# Regex - why these brackets influence on result?

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
(?<=<(.{1,100})>)[^<][^>].+[^<][^>](?=<\/\1>)
```

and the string `<h1>some</h1>`. I want my result to be the insides of a tag, but I can't understand why `[^>]` (3-rd bracket) influences on result.

I tried to process it in my positive lookbehind `'>)'`. If I delete `[^>]`, it works ok, but I don't understand why it counts.
https://regex101.com/r/t25vJh/1

Comment: Your regex is just not correct, as it may overmatch. A `(?<=<([^>]{1,100})>)[\w\W]*?(?=<\/\1>)` regex is more likely to do what you want. However, do not use regex to parse HTML unless there is no other tool you can use for that.

Comment: If you want to get only text inside brackets, you can use `"(?<=<[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,100}>)(.*?)(?=<[/0-9a-zA-Z]+>)"gm` https://regex101.com/r/oaA2ZH/1. But it is better to parse HTML using tools such as Beautiful Soup (Python) or Jsoup in Java.

Comment: You could also use this: `<([0-9a-zA-Z]+)>(.*)</\1>` and select group 2.